# exclude some jaxb generated classes from enunciate

Tags: java, jaxb, enunciate

I am using enunciate and want to exclude certain jaxb generated classes from the documentation. How can this be done?

Is it possible to add the org.codehaus.enunciate.XmlTransient annotation via the xsd?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <enunciate ...>

    <api-classes>
      <exclude pattern="com.mycompany.nonvisible.**"/>
    </api-classes>
    ...
  </enunciate>
```

Comment: Only seems to work for API service classes (REST related). The generated java classes from the xsd's could not be excluded using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding the class by annotating it with `@com.webcohesion.enunciate.metadata.Ignore` (see [user guide](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Excluding-Including-Classes#annotations)). This worked for me.

I also had no success excluding JAXB classes by listing them in enunciate.xml.